# Speeding up data transformations

Tags: python, optimization, transformation

I have a given (by a third party and hence unalterable) input data in the following structure: The data is a list of 4-tuples, each 4-tuple representing a sortie. The first element of each sortie is a list of categories of length 1 to 5 chosen from a total of 20 possible categories (without repetitions); the second element is the number of participants involved; the third is a datetime-object indicating the begin of the sortie; and the last and forth element is a datetime-object indicating the end of the sortie.

Now I have to transform this data into the following format: For each category I need to calculate (a) the numbers of sorties of this category, (b) the total time spent, (c) the average time spent per sortie, (d) the "man hours" total, i.e. the sum of the duration of each sortie multiplied by the number of participants of the selfsame sortie, and (e) the average "man hours" per sortie.

My first naive attempt is the following:

```
def transform (data):
    t = defaultdict (lambda: (0, 0, 0) )

    for row in data:
        delta = row [3] - row [2]
        hours = delta.days * 24 + delta.seconds / 3600
        manHours = row [1] * hours
        for cat in row [0]:
            t [cat] = (t [cat] [0] + 1, t [cat] [1] + hours, t [cat] [2] + manHours)

    return {k: (v [0], v [1], v [1] / v [0], v [2], v [2] / v [0] ) for k, v in t.items () }
```

and I am profiling it with the following:

```
cats = [_ for _ in range (20) ]
for test in range (1000):
    data = [ (random.sample (cats, random.randint (1, 5) ), random.randint (2, 40), datetime.datetime (2013, 1, 1, 8), datetime.datetime (2013, 1, 1, 9) ) for _ in range (1000) ]
    transform (data)
```

using `-m cProfile`.

I have a read a lot of times on stackoverflow the incredible advantages of itertools for performant iterating, grouping, counting, etc up to the point that users prefer using itertools over simple dict- or list-comprehension.

I would like to take advantage of this module, but I am unsure how to get the best out of it. Hence:

**a) In which way can the transformation function be time-optimized (sped up)?**

**b) In which way can `itertools` help me on this endeavour?**

I thank you in advance for your answers.

--

For reference: On my box (AMD Phenom II Quad, 4 GB RAM, 4 GB swap) using `Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:30:32) [GCC 4.7.3] on linux` the profiler spits out: `1000    2.027    0.002    2.042    0.002 trans.py:6(transform)`. Moving from pyhton3 to pypy is not an option.

**EDIT:**
Sample data (using ISO-representation) or use the second code snippet to create (obviously not real-life) data:

```
[([6, 4, 15], 3, '2013-07-31T17:23:00', '2013-07-31T18:40:00'), ([9, 18, 5], 15, '2013-07-08T17:49:00', '2013-07-08T18:57:00'), ([7, 14, 17, 12, 0], 18, '2013-07-20T08:16:00', '2013-07-20T09:06:00'), ([6, 1], 32, '2013-07-31T07:14:00', '2013-07-31T09:01:00'), ([17, 7], 7, '2013-07-05T06:59:00', '2013-07-05T07:52:00')]
```

2013-08-02:
Profiling pillmuncher's idea unfortunately resulted in using numpy being 360% slower than without using it:

```
 1000    1.828    0.002    1.842    0.002 prof.py:8(transform) #original function
 1000    0.159    0.000    8.457    0.008 prof.py:43(transform3) #numpy function
```

Comment: Have you found that this portion of your code is a bottleneck?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is indeed. We need to run this transformation quite often and on different subsets of the total data, which prevents caching.

Comment: And besides, I am always intrigued how to optimize code and how to get the whole juice out of modules I do not often use.

Comment: If you are looking for patterns in the input data, there is indeed: Certain categories tend to have certain numbers of participants. Certain categories tend to group up with certain other categories. Certain categories are mutually exclusive to others. On the other hand, the hour and duration are completely independent of both participants and category.

Comment: There isn't really anything major that you can optimize here. Implement that function as a C extension (try Cython).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np

def transform(data):
    pair_type = np.dtype([('team_size', int), ('duration', 'timedelta64[s]')])
    rec_array = np.core.records.array
    total = np.sum
    mean = np.mean
    one_hour = np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
    tmp = defaultdict(list)
    for categories, team_size, begin, end in data:
        for category in categories:
            tmp[category].append((team_size, end - begin))
    for category, pairs in tmp.items():
        pairs = rec_array(pairs, dtype=pair_type)
        hours = pairs.duration / one_hour
        man_hours = pairs.team_size * hours
        yield category, (
                len(pairs),
                total(hours),
                mean(hours),
                total(man_hours),
                mean(man_hours))

some_data = ...
result = dict(transform(some_data))
```

I don't know if it is any faster. If you try it out, please report the result.

Also, my numpy fu isn't that great. So if anybody knows how to improve it, please tell me.

Comment: Thank you. I am now sitting at a different machine. As soon as I sit again in front of the reference box, I will profile your solution on my HW and tell you the results.

Comment: Thanks again for your idea. Unfortunately numpy just slows it down even more. Take a look at the edit I made to my question. Nevertheless, thanks for the input.